# prepareForSegue getting called twice, with Attempt to present <UINavigationController> while presentation is in progress

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am new to ios programming and asking here, but I visit all the time!  I am stumped at why I am getting this problem, it compiles with no errors and I have checked and checked all my outlets and identifiers in my MainStoryboard.

I have 2 UITableViewControllers, I am passing a string from the first to the second when the user selects an item in the table, so in 
FirstTableViewController.m

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    int sel = indexPath.row;
    if (sel == 0) {
        _keyName = [NSString stringWithString:_string1];
        NSLog(@"the table was selected at cell 0, %@", _string1);
    }
    if (sel == 1) {
        _keyName = [NSString stringWithString:_string2];
    }
    // more code below...
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"ResultsSegue"])
    {
        UINavigationController *navigationController = segue.destinationViewController;
        ResultsViewController *rv = [[navigationController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
        [rv setResults: _keyName];
        NSLog(@"in the progress view, %@", _keyName);
        //rv.delegate = (id)self;
        rv.delegate = self;            
    }
}
```

And in my ResultsViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"in the results, %@", _results);
    NSLog(@"in the results view");
}
```

In the NSlog readout I get:
...
in the progress view, (null)
in the results, (null)
in the progress view, The Right String
Warning: Attempt to present  on

Then when I hit the cancel button to return to the firstTableview and press the detail view again it no longer shows null..

in the progress view, The Right String
in the results, The Right String
in the progress view, The Right String

Comment: How are you doing your segues? Is the first table view embedded in a navigation controller? Do you have more than one navigation controller?

Comment: Just eliminating the easy ones, are you sure _string1 is initialized before the first segues happens.

Comment: They are both embedded in their own navigation controller. _string1 is set in the viewDidUnload,  it uses information from another uitableviewcontroller.. and it shows the data properly in the table.

Comment: also it properly logs the string with "the table was selected at cell 0, The Right String

Comment: Do they both need to be in their own navigation controller? That's not the way it's usually done. Also, if you're using iOS 6, viewDidUnload is no longer called.

Comment: oops sorry I meant viewDidLoad.  I have tried re-creating both in the storyboard, and now I get a warning "Unsupported Configuration, scene is unreachable due to lack of entry points... does not have identifier.  But none of my other tables have identifiers and are embedded in their won navigation controller and work just fine.  I am  not using -instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier why would it show this???

Comment: blah well after deleting the old uitableviewcontrollers in my mainstoryboard and setting all outlets/actions in the new uitableviewcontrollers I still have the same original problem :( but the other warning went away

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The problem is prepareForSegue is called before didSelectRowAtIndexPath. You should just eliminate the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method, and do everything in prepareForSegue. You can use the following line to get the indexPath you need:

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
```

Comment: It is fine to implement both `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` and `prepareForSegue`, but you should NOT perform the transition yourself (the segue will perform it) and you must call `super` in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: @matt, yes, but you can't set a variable in didSelectRowAtIndexPath, and try to use it in prepareForSegue because of the order of execution.

Comment: well that explains why I see the NSlog in the viewDidLoad before the didSelectRowAtIndex NSLog...  which doesn't make sense since I call [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ResultsViewSegue" sender:self]; within the the didSelectRowAtIndex...

Comment: @BubbleMop, do you also have a segue setup in the storyboard from the cell to the next controller?

Comment: In the case of UICollectionView, `NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.collectionview indexPathForCell:sender];`.

Answer (score 4):

Rob's answer helped me, as well - thanks!  I'm coding in Swift, so for those who run into this while Swifting, here's how to get the index (or index row) clicked on in Swift 3:

```
var rowClicked = (self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row)!
```

Answer (score 0):

May be your segue is connection start form the table view cell instead of view controller.

I had same issue I removed the segue from the table view cell and added back at view controller level.

[image]