# prepareForSegue returns nil at first

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm getting `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` when I segue from the cell.

Here's the code:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if indexPath.section == 1 {
        let listIngredients = recipeItem.ingredients[indexPath.row]
        selectedIngredient = listIngredients.ingredient
    }
    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: false)
    performSegueWithIdentifier("showIngredientInRecipe", sender: self)


}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showIngredientInRecipe" {
        let svc = segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController
        let destination = svc.topViewController as! IngredientDetailViewController

        destination.ingredientItem = selectedIngredient


        print("selectedIngredient \n \(selectedIngredient)")

    }

}
```

Here's what I get from the debugger:

```
        selectedIngredient
        nil

        selectedIngredient
        Optional(Ingredient {
            name = Rye Whiskey;
            inStock = 1;
            type = IngredientType {
                name = Spirit;
            };
        })

        fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

As you can see, the `selectedIngredient` prints twice. First as nil, second time with the expected content. If i replace `destination.ingredientItem = selectedIngredient` with `destination.ingredientItem = recipeItem.ingredients[0].ingredient` the segue runs fine with no errors.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [prepareForSegue getting called twice, with Attempt to present <UINavigationController> while presentation is in progress](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14940738/prepareforsegue-getting-called-twice-with-attempt-to-present-uinavigationcontr)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32170456/what-does-fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-valu)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showIngredientInRecipe" {
        if let selectedIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            if selectedIndexPath.section == 1 {
                let listIngredients = recipeItem.ingredients[selectedIndexPath.row]
                selectedIngredient = listIngredients.ingredient
                let svc = segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController
                let destination = svc.topViewController as! IngredientDetailViewController
                destination.ingredientItem = selectedIngredient
                print("selectedIngredient \n \(selectedIngredient)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're checking if indexPath's section is 1 and if it's not it will still perform segue. Make sure your selectable cells are in section 1 (or section 0?) and move your `performSegueWithIdentifier("showIngredientInRecipe", sender: self)` call to if statement to make it more safe.

Comment: Thanks. I moved `performSegueWithIdentifier("showIngredientInRecipe", sender: self)` to the if statement, but I still get nil at first, then the expected results afterwards.

Comment: ```let svc = segue.destinationViewController``` already gives you ```IngredientDetailViewController```I think. Could you tell at which line it gives you nil?

Answer (score 0):

1. Your code is error prone because you can perform segue regardless of
   the section
2. A better way to get the selected item, is to call `indexPathForSelectedRow()` method inside of the delegate

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if indexPath.section == 1 {
         performSegueWithIdentifier("showIngredientInRecipe", sender: self)
    }
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showIngredientInRecipe" {
        //get selected item
        let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow() {
            let selectedIngredient = recipeItem.ingredients[indexPath.row]
            print("selectedIngredient \n \(selectedIngredient)")
            //segue
            let svc = segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController
            let destination = svc.topViewController as! IngredientDetailViewController
            destination.ingredientItem = selectedIngredient
        }
    }
}
```